# Reorganizar posição dos dados listados com php

Tags: php

tenho 3 tabelas, uma com o nome de portaria, outra com o nome de materia, e mais uma com o nome de portaria_has_materia. O foco é na portaria_has_materia. Ela leva os campos de chave estrangeira das tabelas portaria e materia, juntamente com um campo de nome ordem, que é a ordem em que as matérias iram aparecer. Ficando assim:

```
tabela portaria_has_materia
id | idportaria | idmateria | ordem |
1  |      6     |     3     |   1   |
2  |      6     |     6     |   2   |
3  |      6     |     5     |   3   |
4  |      6     |     2     |   4   |
```

A ordem sempre é cadastrada em sequencia na tabela, porém as matérias tem uma ordem correta para aparecer na view, e se não estiverem na ordem correta, tenho que coloca-las, alterando o campo ordem, pois a query será ordenada por ele. Como posso fazer para altera-la e manter a sequencia no banco de dados, para que depois da alteração ela apareça na ordem correta?

o retorno dos dados é feito em json.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public function getMateriaByPortaria()
{

  $this->layout=""; //retornar dados numa tela sem layout

  $materias = $this->PortariaMateriaM->get_all_portaria_materia(); //pega todos os dados da tabela portaria_has_materia

  $data = array(); //array data

  foreach ($materias as $mat) { //foreach que percorre o objeto e armazena no array data
        $data[] = array(
            "idportaria_materia" => $mat->idportaria_materia,
            "ordem" => $mat->ordem,
            "numerada" => $mat->numerada,
            "idportaria" => $mat->idportaria,
            "data_inicio" => $mat->data_inicio,
            "data_fim" => $mat->data_fim,
            "titulo" => $mat->titulo,
            "descricao" => $mat->descricao,
            "descricao_internacional" => $mat->descricao_internacional,
            "assinatura_instrutor" => $mat->assinatura_instrutor,
            "sigla" => $mat->sigla,
            "idmateria" => $mat->idmateria,
            "nome_materia" => $mat->nome_materia,
            "nome_ingles" => $mat->nome_ingles,
            "numero_tempo" => $mat->numero_tempo,
            "carga_horaria" => $mat->carga_horaria,
            "modulo" => $mat->modulo
        );
    }

    print_r(json_encode($data));
    return json_encode($data); //retorna dados do array em json

}
```

Comment: Não estou a entender muito bem a pregunta.. se a chave primaria é o id.. na tabela sempre vai ordenar pelo id..
Na view é colocar o where ordem para ele trazer da forma que vc precisa..
Fiquei sem entender a questão :S Desculpa não poder ajudar

Comment: Nesse caso eu não estou ordenando pela chave primária, pois a posição, que nesse caso é o campo ordem será alterado. Depois de alterado, ele vai me retornar os valores na posição certa, só quero saber como posso alterar esses dados de maneira dinâmica.